# Can I maintain memory in a c++ DLL between function calls?

Tags: c++, dll

So, I'm writing a plugin for a program, which requires that two lots of data are passed to it.  It needs to store that data in-between calls.

so, in psuedo-code:

```
MainFunction()
{
    GenerateData1()
    GenerateData2()
}

GenerateData1()
{
    PassDataToDLL() //(DLL Stores data)
}

GenerateData2()
{
    PassDataToDLL() //(DLL operates on both sets of data, returns results via pointer)
    OutputResults()
}
```

Interestingly, if I modify the above such that after passing data to the dll, the function GenerateData1 calls GenerateData2 itself, then it works!

Am I trying to acheive something that can't be done, or is there a technique that could help?

Comment: How are you loading the dll? Are you linking to it or via LoadLibrary()?

Comment: It's being loaded by someone else in delphi - no idea how they're doing it.  I'll look into the difference though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do

```
class SharedData
{
      //Store all data in this class
};

std::shared_ptr<ShareData> pSharedData = std::make_shared<SharedData>();
```

You can pass **pSharedData** around dlls and it will automatically be deleted when nobody is referencing it.

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for... I'll have a play, thanks